# Files are not installed from recipe

Tags: image, yocto, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to create a custom recipe to sign a u-boot image generated from u-boot.bb.

I have 2 custom recipes:

```
1. u-boot.bb - clones, compiles and deploys u-boot resulting u-boot.elf.
2. u-boot-sign.bb - depends on u-boot.bb. Gets u-boot.elf, passes it through
                    custom signing procedure and deploys the result.
```

For signing I am forced to use a custom procedure which is in a form of python scripts located in external repository.

The part which causes a problem is accessing a deployed u-boot.elf binary file from u-boot.bb recipe. I cannot find a way to expose u-boot.elf binary file to a u-boot-sign.bb recipe.

What should be the correct way of exposing an image binary file from one recipe, to be accessed, signed and deployed in another recipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of sharing the files between recipes and between cross-compilation scope, I used `${datadir}` when installing the binaries (via `do_install`). This allowed me to access all files described by `FILES:${PN}` via `recipe-sysroot`.

`u-boot.bb` - exporting recipe:

```
…
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/u-boot-2016/
    install -m 0644 ${B}/${UBOOT_ELF_BINARY} ${D}${datadir}/u-boot-2016
}

FILES:${PN} = "${datadir}/u-boot-2016"
…
```

`u-boot-sign.bb` - depending recipe

```
…
DEPENDS += " u-boot python3-native"

do_sign() {
    ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/python3-native/python3 sign.py \
                -i ${RECIPE_SYSROOT}${datadir}/u-boot-2016/${UBOOT_ELF_BINARY}

}
…
```

Inspiration from [Here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2019-September/046730.html)

## Edit

I was advised not to transfer files like this using `${datadir}`. For intermediate files the better approach would be to use to use `/firmware` as it is done in `meta-arm`.

`u-boot.bb` - exporting recipe:

```
…
do_install() {
    install -D -p -m 0644 ${B}/${UBOOT_ELF_BINARY} ${D}/firmware/${UBOOT_ELF_BINARY}
}

FILES:${PN} = "/firmware"
SYSROOT_DIRS += "/firmware"
…
```

`u-boot-sign.bb` - depending recipe

```
…
DEPENDS += " u-boot python3-native"

do_sign() {
    ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/python3-native/python3 sign.py \
                -i ${RECIPE_SYSROOT}/firmware/u-boot-2016/${UBOOT_ELF_BINARY}
}
…
```

It also requires to add `/firmware` to `SYSROOT_DIRS`.